# In ReactJS, the onClick on a button inside a map work not properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use an onClick on button inside a map, but when I click on my buttons, sometimes the click is working, sometimes not.

I try to change the tag `<button>` to `<a>`, and the onClick worked correctly. But it's not the same thing semantically, so I would prefer to use button.

Someone have any idea ?

```
    displayActivities = () => {
        const arrayActivities = [
            { value: 'Alarme - Sécurité' },
            { value: 'Architecture - Études' },
            { value: 'Architecture d\'intérieur - Décoration' },
            { value: 'Chauffage - Chaudière' },
            { value: 'Climatisation - Ventilation' },
            { value: 'Construction - Maçonnerie' },
        ];
        return (
            <div className="sef__activity-list" rel="sef__activity-list">
                {arrayActivities.map((activity) => (
                    <button
                        key={activity.value}
                        className="sef__activity-list-button"
                        onClick={() => this.onClickButton(activity.value)}
                        type="button"
                    >
                        {activity.value}
                    </button>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    };

    render() {
        const { isError, value } = this.state;
        const { id } = this.props;
        return (
            <>
                <div className="sef__group-one-field">
                    <label
                        htmlFor={id}
                        className="sef__label"
                        aria-label="Activité"
                    >
                        <span className="fas fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"/>
                        <input
                            id={id}
                            type="text"
                            className={`sef__input ${isError ? 'sef__input--error' : ''}`}
                            placeholder="Peinture, fuite d'eau ..."
                            value={value}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            onFocus={this.onFocus}
                            onBlur={this.onBlur}
                        />
                    </label>
                    {this.displayActivities()}
                    {isError
                    && (
                        <span className="sef__error-message">
                            Merci d&apos;indiquer une activité ou le nom d&apos;un professionnel
                        </span>
                    )}
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
```

Comment: add your onClickButton function as well

Comment: So, you tried to change your tag by what ?

Comment: you don't need to pass the input type, since you're using the tag <button>. 
Can you please share the function onClickButton ?

Comment: @PrakashKarena and @CelsoWellington here my function
```onClickButton = (value) => { this.setState({ value }); };```

Comment: @NipunJain I change the <button> by <a> and every is working correctly. But I prefer the button

Answer (score 0):

> Using an arrow function as click handler will create new instances of function on every render.

I think, if you use `.bind()` to bind `this` reference and add the arguments, it might just work.

Try this:

```js
{arrayActivities.map((activity) => {
const onClick = this.onClickButton.bind(this, activity.value);

return (
  <button
    key={activity.value}
    className="sef__activity-list-button"
    onClick={onClick}
    type="button"
  >

  // rest
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks pritam, I tried this modification but the return returned nothing. The map is working but not the return.

Comment: You'll have to add curly braces, then expression for bind and then return as earlier.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my return and the tag ```<div className="sef__activity-list" rel="sef__activity-list">``` to add your return, and I replaced parenthesis by bracket. But it did return nothing.